# How to detect that the script is running with npm or yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I need to write universal scripts for npm and yarn.

#### package.json for npm:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:clean": "rim-raf dist",
    "test:clean": "rim-raf coverage",
    "clean": "npm run build:clean; npm run test:clean"
  }
}
```

#### package.json for yarn:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:clean": "rim-raf dist",
    "test:clean": "rim-raf coverage",
    "clean": "yarn run build:clean; yarn run test:clean"
  }
}
```

#### package.json for npm and yarn:

I usually use little hack: ***$_***

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:clean": "rim-raf dist",
    "test:clean": "rim-raf coverage",
    "clean": "$_ run build:clean; $_ run test:clean"
  }
}
```

But sometime it does not work correctly. 
Exists some legit way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I found the optimal solution. 
 
I searched in **npm env** and compared it with **yarn env**.
I found the variable ***$npm_execpath*** that contains the path to used package manager. *(For Windows **%npm_execpath%**)*

#### package.json for npm and yarn:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:clean": "rim-raf dist",
    "test:clean": "rim-raf coverage",
    "clean": "$npm_execpath run build:clean; $npm_execpath run test:clean"
  }
}
```

#### My final solution package.json for npm and yarn works on Linux, Windows, Mac:

If add package [cross-var](https://github.com/elijahmanor/cross-var),  scripts works on Linux, Windows and Mac.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:clean": "rim-raf dist",
    "test:clean": "rim-raf coverage",
    "clean": "cross-var $npm_execpath run build:clean; cross-var $npm_execpath run test:clean"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this 3rd party module:

https://github.com/BendingBender/yarpm

Comment: Thanks, I look at it.  It is not exactly what I expected, but if I do not find better solution, I will use yarpm.